# Parse Array inside of an JSON Object with C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to parse an array inside of a json Object but it's not working, here is the code:

```
public void JsonParserPersonal(string file)
        {
            string fullname;
            string email;

            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            var objects = JObject.Parse(json);
            var arrays = JArray.FromObject(json);

            fullname = (string)objects["NameComponents"]["FullName"];
            email = (string)arrays["EmailAddresses"]["ItemValue"];
            SearchReplacePersonal(fullname, email);
        }
```

Here is the JSON data:

```
{
    "NameComponents": {
        "FullName": "XXX"
    },
    "EmailAddresses": [
        {
            "IsPersonal": true,
            "IsBusiness": false,
            "FieldName": "Email1Address",
            "DisplayTitle": "Email",
            "ItemValue": "xxx@yyy.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

All I want is to get the "ItemValue" inside of "EmailAddresses".
When I run this code, this is the error I get:

***System.ArgumentException: 'Object serialized to String. JArray instance expected.'***

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing `JArray`, you should specify the `index`

```
var objects = JObject.Parse(json);
var jarray = objects["EmailAddresses"];

Console.WriteLine((string)objects["NameComponents"]["FullName"]);
Console.WriteLine((string)jarray[0]["ItemValue"]);
```

Or iterate `JArray`

```
foreach(var item in jarray)
{
    foreach(JProperty property in item.Children())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} - {property.Value}");
    }                
}
```

Comment: Parsing the array is unnecessary - can just be `var jarray = objects["EmailAddresses"];`

Comment: Thanks @stuartd for the finding. Have updated the post